# R-Backtesting of a Model

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

I have to evaluate the forecasting power of my model.

On my database I have 5 years of hourly data of 150 variables .

What I want to do?

1) OLS regression using the data of the first 4 years and then save variable's coefficient.

**Result of my regression**:

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 271.6 on 34565 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9552,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9545 
F-statistic:  1479 on 498 and 34565 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

2) Use the saved coefficients combined with the data of the last years to forecast my Y and then compare the forecasted Y to the actual Y.

I know how to do 1) but i don't know how to do 2).

Any suggestion?

Best Regards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know which R package you are using to build the OLS regression model, generally to predict the `predict` function is used to predict the values based on certain parameters. Below is the link for predict function documentation.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-3/topics/Predict

Comment: Thank you so much.